# Doctrine 2, update value switch

Tags: doctrine-orm

with native SQL:

```
UPDATE a SET active = NOT active WHERE id = 1
```

how to write this with Doctrine2 builder? I tried:

```
$q = $this->createQueryBuilder('a');
$q->update()->set('a.active', $q->expr()->not('a.active'))->getQuery()->execute();
```

with no luck

Answer (score 1):

I think you need something like that, for Entity:

```
$qb = $this->em->createQueryBuilder();
$q = $qb->update('models\A', 'a')
    ->set('a.active', $qb->expr()->not('a.active'))
    ->where('a.id = ?1')
    ->setParameter(1, $id)
    ->getQuery();
$p = $q->execute();
```

For native SQL:

```
use Doctrine\ORM\Query\ResultSetMapping;
$rsm = new ResultSetMapping();

$q = $this->em->createNativeQuery('UPDATE a SET active = NOT active WHERE id = ?', $rsm);
$q->setParameter(1, $id);
$q->exectute();
```

For native queries without entity manager you can use:

> \Doctrine\DBAL\Query\QueryBuilder